# Unable to get the key value of the item clicked in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

During on click on each boxes I would like to get the `tags` of the corresponding box. But while console log the print tags, it is displaying as undefined. I have tried both cases like `e.currentTarget.tags` and  `e.target.tags`, but still not getting the correct result. Could someone please help ?

Demo link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-elgamal-lyyih?file=/src/App.js:87-1914

```
const blogData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Cypress tests",
    description: "Add the E2E cypress UI tests",
    createddate: "19 September 2020",
    tags: "cypress"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Jmeter tests",
    description: "Performance test using Jmeter tool",
    createddate: "15 August 2020",
    tags: ["jmeter", "performance"]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Basic Unix commands",
    description: "Learn basic unix commands in git bash",
    createddate: "10 July 2020",
    tags: "unix"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Postman",
    description: "Api testing using postman",
    createddate: "1 June 2020",
    tags: ["postman", "api"]
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [showColor, setShowColor] = useState("");
  const [findTag, setFindTag] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResults(blogData);
  }, [blogData]);

  const randomizedHex = (e) => {
    setFindTag(e.currentTarget.tags);
    console.log("Print tag:", findTag);
    const randomColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    setShowColor(randomColor);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrap">
        {searchResults.map((blog) => (
          <article onClick={randomizedHex} className="equalBox">
            <section>
              <span key={blog.id}> {blog.id} </span>
            </section>
            <section>
              <div key={blog.tags}>{blog.tags}</div>
            </section>
          </article>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needs to pass the `blog` object to the callback:

```js
  const randomizedHex = (blog) => {
    setFindTag(blog.tags);
    console.log("Print tag:", findTag);
    const randomColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    setShowColor(randomColor);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrap">
        {searchResults.map((blog) => (
          <article onClick={() => { randomizedHex(blog); }} className="equalBox">
            <section>
              <span key={blog.id}> {blog.id} </span>
            </section>
            <section>
              <div key={blog.tags}>{blog.tags}</div>
            </section>
          </article>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: You right! You can also call the function like `onClick={() => randomizedHex(blog)}` without the `{}`.

Comment: @dazs True, although returning `false` from an `onclick` event listener has significance so I avoid implicit return values from arrow functions unless I actually want the return value.

Comment: @RossAllen Thank you, if my blog has got bit different JSON structure, can we get `tags` directly from that ?

Comment: @soccerway I don't think I understand your follow up question. Can you post a new question and link it here?

Comment: Thanks Allen, I do have a code sandbox link to share, but I didn't raise a new question yet. Its same question but the blog object structure is different. https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-resonance-fogf9?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-resonance-fogf9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @RossAllen Added the comments and demo link above